# Intuition on this definition of a poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, poisson-process

I'm in a context of defaultable assets (stochastic process with a negative jump at some point). The paper I'm reading says that the arrival \textbf{rate} of default is $\psi_t$. What does it mean exactly? The paper uses the identity $\mathbb{E}_t[d N_t] = \psi_td t$, but I'm not familiar with this (abuse of?) notation. The paper can be found [here](https://www.galonuno.com/uploads/1/3/4/6/134687692/term_structure_november_2021.pdf) (p. 9). Any help, please? I would appreciate as well books about stochastic integrals (in particular on poisson processes). Thanks.

Comment: A link to the paper would be useful. I would expect something like $\Bbb E[\mathrm dN_t] = \lambda\mathrm dt$, not sure what $\psi_t$ is. Also, $\int_a^b dX_t = X_b - X_a$ for any stochastic integrand $X$. With regards to the books, just googling gives some openly available notes on Poisson processes, why don't you start there.

Comment: let me edit the question, I forgot the dt. Sorry for that and thanks for your answer, @Ilya

Comment: regarding $\psi_t$, what we just know is that it's "some" deterministic function of $t$. Not much information, tho.

Comment: ok, then it's just time-dependent intensity. There are Poisson processes of that kind, but I'm not sure which book covers those. So what's your question? please state it as precise as possible

Comment: I recommend the book D. Lamberton, B. Lapeyre, *Introduction to Stochastic Calculus  Applied to Finance*. It  covers the Poisson process which is often underrepresented in in the literature so that practitioners can follow. One does not always  have to read massive volumes such as Protter's book.

Comment: @Ilya, my question is why is true that $\mathbb{E}_t[d N_t] = \psi_t dt$ and how to understand that notation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @KurtG.!

Comment: BTW, if you are only interested in defaultable assets: The first jump of a Poisson process is sufficient. It has a a very simple definition $1_{\{\tau\le t\}}$ where the default time $\tau$ is an exponential random variable with intensity $\lambda\,.$ This $\lambda$ is often taken to be time dependent in the credit model literature.

Comment: That's indeed what I had in mind, yes, @KurtG., thanks! Do you know by chance how to answer my question of how to prove that $\mathbb{E}_t[d N_t] = \psi_t dt$? Or at least understand the notation in a more "mathematical way"? I get the intuition of the instantaneous rate balboa, but I would like to understand it formally as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a credit default model the simplest way to define the default time $\tau$ is to draw a uniform $U\sim [0,1]$ and put it into the inverse of the CDF of the exponential distribution. With a time dependent default intensity $\psi(t)$ this CDF is
$$
F(t)=1-\textstyle\exp(-\int_0^t\psi(s)\,ds)\,.
$$
Then set $\tau=F^{-1}(U)\,.$ This ensures that the survival probability is what we expect:
$$\mathbb P(\tau>t)=\mathbb P(U>F(t))=1-F(t)=\textstyle\underline{\underline{\exp(-\int_0^t\psi(s)\,ds)\,.}}
$$
As far as credit default is concerned we could stop here because
an entity defaults typically only once.

To define a Poisson process with time dependent intensity (an *inhomogeneous* PP) we draw independent uniforms $U_1,U_2,...$ and define independent exponential waiting times
$\tau_1,\tau_2,\dots$ in the same way as above. The jump times are
$$
 \sigma_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\tau_i
$$
and the Poisson process is
$$
N_t=\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1_{\{\sigma_i\le t\}}\,.
$$
The notation $\mathbb E[dN_t]=\psi(t)\,dt$ is nothing else than an abbreviation of the fact that
$N_t-\int_0^t\psi(s)\,ds$ is a martingale which we can write also as:
$$
\mathbb E[N_t|{\cal F}_s]=N_s+\textstyle\int_s^t\psi(u)\,du\,.
$$

Comment: +1 overall, but to me $\Bbb E[\mathrm dN_t] = \psi_t\mathrm dt$ only means that $N_t - N_s = \int_s^t\psi_u \mathrm du + (A_t - A_s)$ where $\Bbb E A_t$ is constant in time, it does not really have to be a martingale.

Comment: @Ilya I agree. Did not read that paper. Seems like one of those where authors rely a bit too much on readers already knowing what they mean. It is cheap to clarify such things.

Comment: What I've meant is that most likely $A$ is a martingale indeed, but to be completely formal, it does not have to be for one to use that abuse of notation.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but anyways it's a minor point that likely does not deserve us discussing it in detail.

Comment: @Ilya I meant that $\mathbb E[dN_t]$ is sloppy notation that does not have a unique interpretation. So we agree.

Comment: Thanks both for your comments. Now it's clear!

Comment: Hi, I'm re-reading the paper and it's written $\mathbb{E} [d N_t] = \psi_t$... I had the same idea than you and that's why I thought it was times $ dt$, but it's not, @KurtG.

Comment: If you want me to answer this comment please say where exactly and what exactly is written in that 50p preprint. Having said that: I do not have a huge appetite to fix their typos and make their notation rigorous. What I have to say is in the answer above.

Comment: @R__ Using a search engine I found one occurrence of "Poisson process $dN_t$" on page 12 and five or six other occurrences of the words "Poisson process with rate parameter $\eta$" (or sometimes another symbol). To make a long story short: if you link to the correct paper there is nowhere an abuse of notation. It is all standard and as I wrote in the answer. Case closed.